# SQL ( How do I use the CONCAT function)

Tags: sql, concatenation

How do I use the CONCAT function on SQL.

Comment: Are you running into unexpected issues trying to use it? If so, show us how are you using it ([edit] your post to include an example). Have you found the online documentation for the function?

Answer (score 4):

That is pretty straightforward

```
SELECT CONCAT('hey', 'ho');
```